# Find the smallest number that when multiplied with a decimal will give a whole number

Tags: fractions, gcd-and-lcm

Given a decimal number $x$ ($3.25$ for example), how would I find $y$ so that $x * y$ equals a whole number?

Comment: $3.25=3\frac{25}{100}=3\frac14$, so $y=4$ will do.

Comment: so convert to a fraction and multiply by the denominator?

Comment: You probably mean the smallest integer $y$, otherwise the answer is $y=1/x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the decimal part and write it as a fraction.  E.g. for 3.25, take the 0.25 and write it as $25/100$. Reduce it to lowest terms:  $1/4$.  The denominator will be the number you want.  Another example, 5.222.  Fractional part = $222/1000$.  Reduce: $111/500$, so $500$ is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The common idea is to check how many digits are to the right of the decimal point. For each digit, multiply by $10$. For example here, $3.25$ has two digits, so you'd multiply by $10 \cdot 10 = 100$.

Comment: but this won't always give the smallest number, i.e, 3.25 * 4 < 3.25 * 100

Comment: Then doing what Hagen von Eitzen suggested will do the trick.